# IE quirks mode: image display block

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, padding, quirks-mode

In IE's quirks mode, it appears images remain inline when set to position absolute.

```
<li style='padding-left:25px;position:relative'>
    Hello, I am some text
    <img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/2378690.jpg' style='position:absolute;left:0px;'/>
</li>
```

Is there any way to make this behave like it were in standards mode (with just CSS)?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Make the CSS work for both standards and quirks mode. In quirks mode, the image is shifted to the right 25px, due to its container's padding.

Comment: "display:block" on the <img>?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already, but it seems to ignore it.

Comment: @Azimisov - why do you want to use Quirksmode at all? Quirksmode is basically an IE5.5 compatibility mode. There really is no good reason to be using it these days. Put a doctype at the top of your page, switch to standards mode, and everyone will be much better off.

Comment: That's true. I think that's what I decided I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

> Put a doctype at the top of your page, switch to standards mode, and everyone will be much better off.